# Restore mysql data from .MYD .MYI .SDI files

Tags: mysql, linux

I made a big mistake and I remove some files from /var/lib/mysql directory... so my mysql server stop working and I execut a command to restore those files.

Now my mysql is running but without databases I used to have, by the way I got the directories for each database, those directories have files with this extension: .MYD, .MYI and .sdi. I want to know if its possible to restore my data from this files.

Thank you!!

My mysql version is 8.0.28-ubuntu0.20.04.3

Comment: (1) Create a table (the structure must match **precisely**). (2) Stop server. (3) Repalce files with saved ones. (4) Start server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.